# Creating tables for my todo list application

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have started working on a todo list application in php. I haven't worked on relational database earlier so i am confused about the structure of my database. I want to keep it simple.

This is my plan:

- *Users*
  U_id,
  username,
  password,
  email
- *Tasks*
  t_id,
  task_name,
  description,
  u_id reference users table
- *Lists*
  l_id,
  list_name,
  ?

My main cause of confusion is

1. How to connect lists and tasks?    //each user will be able to create multiple lists e.g.-  Home, personal, office, Home work etc.
2. What is the best way to connect users and list?    //each user can have multiple lists with multiple tasks, so how to manage this.

Comment: Use a framework with an ORM, e.g. http://symfony.com

Comment: I can use ORM at any time but a programmer should be able to do such kind of stuff without the use of framework.

Comment: Fair point. A programmer would also know to look for an SQL tutorial... (And, fwiw, the question reads like homework from a 1st-year CS student. If that is your case, I'd renew my suggestion: learn to do this stuff using an ORM, then dive into the gory details and understand what's underneath.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know all the tasks in a list you need a relation table if a task can belong to one or more list.

- Users U_id, username, password, email //a user can have zero or one or many lists
- Tasks t_id, task_name, description // a task can belong to zero or one or many lists
- Lists  L_id, list_name, U_id // a list can belong to one and only one User
- Lists_Tasks t_id, L_id // a task can belong to one or more list

to get all the tasks form a list

```
SELECT T.* FROM Tasks AS T
JOIN Lists_Tasks AS L_T ON T.t_id = L_T.t_id
WHERE L_T.l_id = id_from_the_list
```

to get all the Lists from a User

```
SELECT * FROM Lists WHERE U_id = id_of_user
```

Answer (score 0):

1. n:m relation table: which list is connected with a task
2. each list can have a u_Id field. When more than one user can have the same list then do n:m relation, too

example for n:m relation:

list_task_relation: list_id, task_id

Answer (score 0):

Keep a U_id is your *Lists* table.

Also, keep a l_id in your *Tasks* table

Read [MySQL Tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tutorial.html) before you go forward.